# Replacing a list element by pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

This function takes list, index number, and a replacement string. It goes through the list and replaces the element at the given index with the replacement string. What I'm not sure of is what case the pattern in the last line is trying to catch.

```
-- e.g., listSet1 ["a","x","k"] 2 "d" = ["a", "d","k"]
listSet1 (x:xs) 1 y = y:xs
listSet1 (x:xs) n y = x : listSet1 xs (n-1) y
listSet1 xs _ _ = xs
```

Comment: Instead of asking what the last line matches, *very carefully* say what the first two lines match. Reveal itself, the answer will.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it really should be written `listSet1 [] _ _ = []`. There are very good reasons to avoid "catch-all" patterns in most cases--they tend to make code harder to understand and can lead to silent breakage when type definitions change. They make sense when one or two constructors need to change and multiple others pass through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last pattern handles the end of the list. You won't notice it unless you try and replace an index not present in the list (try it!)

Comment: Thanks! After commenting that line out, I see it's catch all statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should add one of the following lines to the top of every Haskell file: `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` or `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}`. These go above the `module Foo where` line if you have one of those. With one of these in place, commenting out that last pattern will give you a warning saying exactly what is not matched.